# Tomcat starting slow ( AprLyfecycleListener )

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, tomcat, tomcat6

I just wanted to know why my tomcat is starting so slow.
I was able to change the timeout and then I saw the starting log

```
Feb 24, 2015 4:24:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which [...]
Feb 24, 2015 4:26:11 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 24, 2015 4:26:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 127659 ms
Feb 24, 2015 4:26:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 24, 2015 4:26:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.43
Feb 24, 2015 4:26:11 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 24, 2015 4:26:11 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Feb 24, 2015 4:26:11 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/13  config=null
Feb 24, 2015 4:26:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 301 ms
```

Analysing this:

```
Feb 24, 2015 4:24:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
Feb 24, 2015 4:26:11 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
```

and...

```
Feb 24, 2015 4:26:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 127659 ms
```

The start of this **AprLifecycleListener** is taking 2 minutes, I saw some other logs on the internet, and they start instantly.

I'm using eclipse luna, tomcat 6, java 6, and ubuntu 12.04 x64

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could inspect the startup using `strace`.

Comment: Ok, gonna search about this and do it. Thanks.